# Should the CNAME end with a . or not

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-certificate-manager

I'm trying to validate my dns ownership for certificate verification in AWS. AWS says, add a CNAME record in your provider with this specific `CNAME name` and `CNAME value`
something.example.com. and somethingelse.soms.aws.

Both these fields end with a .

Google domain says it cannot allow a . at the end in CNAME name field. I'm wondering if I should remove the . in the CNAME value also or not? does anybody know?

AWS keeps saying `pending validation` - not sure if it validated and failed or it never checked for validation yet - (BAD UX, but that's a topic for another day/so-question/discussion) So I'm not sure if I first try with a . and then remove and try. Confused.

In AWS this is what I see

[image]

In Google domains this is what I see

[image]

Comment: It shoudn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that google automatically adds yourdomain.com in the end of CNAME name. so be careful and double check after you add the value.

It should only be `something.example.com` **not** `something.example.com.example.com`

Also google domain always adds a . to the end of CNAME value. If you added a . it will not, but if didn't add, it will add a .

**Double standards** between `CNAME name` and `CNAME value` fields, go figure!